# Is it possible to change views, once during the start of an event handler and once during end?

Tags: c#, wpf

I get data from database on a click.
I have an event handler which when triggered should show "data retrieving..." in status bar and should change to "Ready" again just before the event handler ends.

But the text updates only once, the second Ready one. How is it generally done?

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
this.footerText = "Waiting for dataRetreival";
someRandomTimeTakingMethod(); //Gets Data from DB.
this.footerText = "Ready";
}
```

Even though code executes line 2, the view updates only when the function is over, ie only the second one actually works.

Comment: C# or VB? If you have some code to show, please include it, as that helps us give you better answers and makes the question more useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your data-intensive work on a background thread so the UI can update properly. This provides the best user experience.

To elaborate on FZysset's answer with some code...

```
    private async void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        footerText.Text = "Waiting for dataRetreival";
        IsEnabled = false;
        await SomeRandomTimeTakingMethodAsync();
        IsEnabled = true;
        footerText.Text = "Ready";
    }

    private async Task SomeRandomTimeTakingMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().Next(2, 5)));
        // or await Task.Run(() => { ... });
    }
```

The above example allows you to leverage await/async that was introduced in .NET 4.5. Notice how nicely it flows? No nonsense!

We're putting stuff onto the background thread so the UI can remain unblocked (thus it will show your updates to your status bar and allow user interaction.) Of course, you have to be careful not to update anything on the UI from your background thread.

If you are using an older version of .NET, you can just use TPL without async/await:

```
    private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        footerText.Text = "Waiting for dataRetreival";
        IsEnabled = false;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            SomeRandomTimeTakingMethod();
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            footerText.Text = "Ready";
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private void SomeRandomTimeTakingMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().Next(2, 5)));
    }
```

Two important things to note about the latter example:

1. You must provide `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to the `ContinueWith` call, or you will encounter exceptions because the continuation is not on the UI thread. You must get the context in a method that isn't running on a background thread.
2. You will want to check for exceptions on the `Task` object in your `ContinueWith`.

This example is very rudimentary though. If you were to have a bunch of background operations kicked off with click handlers, you'd want to give yourself some helper classes/services to make life easier. (And investigate MVVM, which I cannot tell if you are using.)

A colleague of mine gave a presentation on using various asynchronous patterns in C# and .NET. You can check it out here: https://github.com/mtusk/TplLunchAndLearn

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're "someRandomTimeTakingMethod" is launched on the UI Thread. Therefore it will not update the view until it is finished.

To go around this you have the following possibilities :

- Make your method "someRandom..." asynchronous with a task, and use the await operator : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx
- Launch your randomTimeTaking method into a thread, and launch an event when your execution is finished, to update the footer text

I strongly recommend you the first option, for some sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873191.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to run those lines asynchronously. You can do that using the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => footerText = "Waiting for dataRetreival");
    someRandomTimeTakingMethod(); //Gets Data from DB.
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => footerText = "Ready");
}
```

Comment: The code throws an error, The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I tried the following code
 `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => footerText = "Please wait for data retreival");
   }));`

Which again throws the same error...

Dispacther should be invoked from Task factory?

Comment: This solution is incredibly invalid. It should be immediately obvious to anyone who has done any async programming.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do it using Dispatcher. The original post is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fce9b7b-4a13-4c8d-8c3e-562667851baa/forcing-update-of-ui-before-my-function-exits?forum=wpf).

The code is:-

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  UpdateUI("Please wait for data retrieval", delegate() { someRandomTimeTakingMethod(); });
  this.footerText = "Ready";
}

public delegate void NoArgsDelegate();

public void UpdateUI(string description, NoArgsDelegate operation)
    {
        this.FooterText= description;

        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, operation);

        dispatcherOperation.Completed += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                                                                   
            frame.Continue = false; 
        };
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);

    }
```

If my understanding is right, this uses Asynchronous programming, not different thread. The thread will update UI first and then call the someRandomTimeTakingMethod().